# Is it possible to audit viewing of list items in SharePoint Server 2016?

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, auditing

Is it possible to get audit logs when users view lists or list items in SharePoint Server 2016?

On the *Configure Audit Settings* page in SP2016 you can select to audit: *"Opening or downloading documents, **viewing items in lists**, or viewing item properties.*" which leads one to believe that it is possible.

I have [read Microsoft's documentation,](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/configure-audit-data-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#ID0EAADAAA=SharePoint_Server_2019,_2016,_2013) but the wording is very vague, but they say that *"Pages (such as .aspx) aren't considered documents"*.

I get opening of documents in the logs, but why can't I get it to work with list items? Or is it just not possible?

I found two posts online that would indicate that it might in fact not be possible:
[Get all list item ID's that have been read by user - from audit log - SPList.GetItemByUniqueId - value does not fall within the expected range](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214523/get-all-list-item-ids-that-have-been-read-by-user-from-audit-log-splist-get)
https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/sharepoint/auditpolicy/view/listitem.aspx

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Run a custom report and select both the options  : Opening and downloading documents and editing items, for me it worked and displayed both viewed and update actions on list items.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input!  
  
I do get events in the audit log for Update and Edit of list items, but never for Viewing an item... and the results are the same with the pre-defined reports compared to a custom report.  

[This guy here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214523/get-all-list-item-ids-that-have-been-read-by-user-from-audit-log-splist-get) says:  

"...it seems that SharePoint 2013 doesn't record events for viewing a list item. Because when you view a list item you actually open a template, the audit log has an entry for that template and not the item."

Comment: I'm leaning towards it being impossible to get Views of (custom) lists and list items therein to show up in Audit logs in SharePoint, despite Microsoft's wording in the GUI.  
  
I might open a Microsoft case soon to confirm this.